# How can I reduce the output voltage in a simple way?

Tags: usb, semiconductors, usb-device, smartphones

I want to connect my old smartphone (Galaxy S4) directly to a charger without battery.

I want to connect plus and minus pins, so I need 3.8 V input, but the charger gives 5 V.

What is the best and simplest way to reduce the output voltage? It can be 3.8 V or something lower, I don't know, maybe 3.6 V or 3.7 V.

I read that I could use a [1N4001](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) diode, but I don't know if this is good and safe.

Is there a connector that can be connected directly to the pins so that I don't have to solder?

Comment: You should perform a mini experiment with the phone using a small series resistor and the battery. Try powering your phone from the battery but, each time increase the series resistor value from a really low value (starting at 10 milli ohm) to 100 milli ohm. At some value of resistance it may start to be problematic. This value needs to be established. Try it at warmer and cooler temperatures too. Once established, then maybe it can be achieved from a 5 volt charger (plus interface circuit).

Comment: did you try plugging the charger into the charging port instead of the battery port? Many phones will run without batteries

Answer (score 3):

Using a 1N4007 or similar diode has several problems.

First, the voltage drop is a typical 0.7 V, so the difference between your input voltage and output voltage has to be some multiple of that. If you start with 5.0 V one diode gets you to 4.3 V which is too high for your requirements, two gets you down to 3.6 V which is close to what you're looking for.

But that 0.7 V drop is not constant. It will vary slightly from diode to diode as well as with forward current and temperature.

Here's a simulation using two 1N4007 diodes from a 5 V source, varying the current from 50 mA to 1500 mA, and at three temperatures, 10\$^\circ\$ C, 25\$^\circ\$ C, and 40\$^\circ\$ C.

[image: Diode voltage drop simulation]

You can see from the measurement that the difference between 50 mA @ 40\$^\circ\$ C and 1500 mA @ 10\$^\circ\$ C is nearly half a volt, and the output voltage gets well below the 3.6 V you may have expected as the current gets higher.

A smartphone can have a wide range of current draw depending on what it's doing, in standby it may be milliamps, when running several apps and transmitting it may be over an amp. You would probably need something a bit more stable than diodes to keep the voltage within the allowable range. A switching regulator or LDO would be the usual things to use for this.

Comment: A smartphone should also be designed for battery voltage between 3.2V and 4.2V so it's okay if the voltage changes by that much

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to reduce an input voltage of 5V down to 3.6V. I will try to give you several solutions below:

1. Low-Dropout Regulator (LDO): LDO will allow you to safely drop the voltage and provide a constant amount of current. In general, the way an LDO works is that there is an internal zener-type circuit which drops the voltage at the cost of wasting a few milliamps of current. This means that although it is not the most energy efficient solution, it may be the cheapest or smallest depending on your current needs. This implementation can be done with a single LDO IC, and a few bypass capacitors.
2. Buck Converter: This is a switching supply which is more efficient generating the lower voltages based from the higher input voltage. In general, these circuits require other components to operate, such as inductors to smooth the output, bias resistors to set the voltage, and capacitors to couple the input and output lines along with setting the startup speeds. This solution may be the most robust and power efficient, but will likely cost more and take up more space.
3. Op-amp Buffer: This implementation takes in a higher voltage and then lowers it using a resistor voltage divider, and then buffers the output using an op-amp in voltage follower configuration. This Option is good for providing reference voltages, and may work depending on the current sourcing ability of the chosen op-amp. This implementation may be the most accurate in terms of providing the desired output voltage, as the op-amp will continuously regulate the output. to match the input.

> I read that I could use a 1N4001 diode, but I don't know if this is good and safe.

You may be able to get away with using two diodes with a 0.7V drop, or a single diode with a larger drop, however this may provide varying output as temperature and manufacturing processes may yield diodes with varying characteristics. These characteristics are typically provided in the manufacturers datasheet.

> Is there a connector that can be connected directly to the pins so that I don't have to solder?

Unfortunately without images or dimensions, it will be difficult to source the connector. Your best bet may be to buy the same battery and remove the connector or cut the connector from a dead battery which you might already have. If the connector is embedded into the battery, this might be impossible, so you might end up having to solder wires.

Answer (score 0):

Most linear regulator can hardly handle 1A current. Therefore, LDO isn't recommended.

What you should do is carefully choose a buck converter. However, I have heard that some buck converters' actual current is much smaller than rating current, or the chip temperature and output ripple go crazy when approaching its rating current level, which the the former might just burn itself out, but the latter might seriously damage your phone.